# Android Edit Text Cursor position issues

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making a text editor in android, I am using a multi-line edit text that holds all the text and all the editing is done on the same edit text.

I have one issue:

When i started working on the application, the cursor kept on the first position of the edit text. every time i use to enter text, the cursor did not move, rather the text kept on adding.
then i used this short piece of code to bring the cursor at the end of the edittext

```
edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().length());
```

Now the problem is that i am unable to edit any text that has already been written in the edittext, as when i ever i try to edit it, the cursor jumps to the last position.

What i want is that my cursor should move to the position where i want to add or edit text. it is not allowing me to do that right now.

Additional things:
I am using a text watcher and all of the functionalities are being implemented in the text watcher. secondly i am using post function in `onResume` of my activity to implement certain functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

use append method for this, it will show the cursor at the last :

```
etEditText.append("Text here");
```